# Can autorefresh function still work after I publish (export) a report from SQL server report builder?

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

I'm learning how to use Microsoft SQL server report builder 3.0. I know there is a function in the report called `autorefresh`. It works when I simply run the report within the report builder. I'm thinking can it still be refreshed after the report is exported.

Another question may related to this autorefresh functionality. When I add dataset into report builder, does it actually load the data into report builder or set up a link between report builder and database? If it sets up a link does that mean when I change something in database, it will reflect on my report builder after I refresh it.

All I want to do is keep the report up to date even after I export it.

Really keen to know the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Make properties visible(View Tab > Check Box View)

Then navigate to report properties(Click on blue space around page). It should say **Report** in bold at the top of properties.

Expand the **Other** list and **AutoRefresh** is the first one.

It's by default set to 0. It's measured in seconds so changing it to 30 will make your report refresh every 30 seconds.

Just so you know, you'll find that even though reportBuilder is the new SSRS(BIDS), it's still very, very similar. So don't feel like you need to always only look at Report Builder only. SSRS tutorials and other facts will be either identical or similar enough to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks @Stephan. But I would like to know if `AutoRefresh` still works after I export the report?

Comment: I think AutoRefresh is a setting for report server. If you look up how to do other ways in SSRS, I'm sure it be I'll come up and should be the same